# IQueritable MVC can't find the database

Tags: sql, model-view-controller

I'm working on a MVC project and I can't fix the following:

```
   public class localitatiRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetLocalitati()
    {
        IQueryable<localitati> loc = db.localitatis;  //ERROR at db
        SelectList lst = new SelectList(loc, "idlocalitate", "localitate");
        return lst;
    }
}
}
```

Can't find the db.Isn't that the table from the databases? Or that line

```
  db.localitatis
```

where should it be implemented? No idea where to find to fix this issue.Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Which database framework are you using, and which programming language? Is it Entity Framework and C#, for instance?

Also, think about this: does it make sense to assign a database table object reference to a IQueryable? Probably not. Most likely, you have to run some other method on your table - such as `db.mytable.get(someId)` - which (might) return an IEnumerable of some sort.

Actually, if you are programming in C#, you might consider not setting the expected return type for your variable explicitly, and instead use the generic *var* type that automatically assigns the correct type:

```
var loc = db.mytable.someGetterMethod(xyz);
```

Hope that helps!